# Issue with Isolated scopes in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to run this program and I see no output. Can you please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head ng-app="myApp">
<title>Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"   href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.2/css/foundation.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div my-directive my-url="http://www.google.com" my-click="Click me">

</div>
</body>
<script>
angular.module('myApp',[]).directive('myDirective',function()
{
    return
    {
        restrict : 'AE',
        replace : true,
        scope :
        {
           myURL :'@',
           myClick : '@'
        },
        template : '<a href="{{myURL}}">{{myLinkText}}</a>'
    };
 });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i made your code error free but still i cant see any thing in output....may i know expected output.....http://plnkr.co/edit/auTH8bStpHrX7r8xUJbI?p=preview.....   hope that some one can help with this

Comment: Thank you. You are not seeing 'Click me' button because the template definition is wrong. Please modify the template part of code to this and it gives 'Click Me' as Output. The expectation is it should redirect to google.com when clicked on it, right? Not sure if I am missing anything template: '<a href="{{myURL}}">{{myClick}}</a>'

Comment: Directives have changed quite a bit in the previous versions, especially around the isolate scope. You are using a rather old version of AngularJS. Is it possible for you to upgrade to 1.5 or even 1.4?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you placed the root of your Angular app in the header and not in the body.
Change the location of the `ng-app="myApp"` attribute from the head to the **body** or **html** elements

```
<html ng-app="myApp"> <!-- new location -->
<head > <!-- ng-app="myApp" it was here -->
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"   href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.2/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>

</head>
```

In the **directive** `{{myLinkText}}` does not exists, it should be renamed for `{{myClick}}`

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. It is still not working. I get a blank page.

Comment: I see these couple of errors in the browser console :                                                      isolatedscopes2.html:22 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
angular.js:78                                                                                          Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

some how by spending whole day i am able to display the text and able to click it but failing to redirect to the mentioned URL,i am getting error in console like `Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kepTWNDiIvLI8Afnp4HIBg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`you can found the same [here in console](http://plnkr.co/edit/auTH8bStpHrX7r8xUJbI?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Any ideas on resolving the error in console and how to get this working ?

Comment: unfortunately i too dont know and waiting for some one who knows about this