# Parent and child scopes in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can anyone please provide me with simple examples to understand parent and child scopes in angular better?
I have tried the following but it prints hello {{person}} as output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Simple app </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 ng-app="MyApp3" ng-controller="ParentController">
<h1 ng-controller="ChildController">hello {{person}}</h1>
</h1>
</body>
<script>
var app=angular.module('MyApp3',[]);
app.controller('ParentController',function($scope)
{
    $scope.person =
    {
        name : "Angular"
    };
});
app.controller('ChildController',function($scope)
{
    $scope.person.name="Angular";
    $scope.person.age=40;
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to access the `name` property of `person` - `{{ person.name }}`

Comment: Also your html is invalid. `<h1>` can't be child of `<h1>` and script tag is outside body

Comment: Here is the best write up on understanding scope that I have seen: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. Notice the `<div>` elements to contain the controller scopes.

You can see how the `ChildController` is accessing the person in the `ParentController` because the object shows the name "Child" even though it is outside of the `ChildController` `<div>`.

```js
var app=angular.module('MyApp3',[]);
app.controller('ParentController',function($scope)
{
    $scope.person =
    {
        name : "Parent"
    };
});
app.controller('ChildController',function($scope)
{
    $scope.person.name="Child";
    $scope.person.age=40;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Simple app </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js">
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp3" ng-controller="ParentController">
<h1>This shows the object</h1>
  <p>{{person}}</p>
  
<div ng-controller="ChildController">  
<h1>This shows the name</h1>
  <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That made the concepts clear. Can you please take a look at this post also and help me with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176742/issue-with-isolated-scopes-in-angular/41185503?noredirect=1#comment69572857_41185503